# Ratio of Selberg integral

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, cv.complex-variables, inequalities, integration, special-functions

I'm considering a ratio of incomplete [Selberg integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selberg_integral):
$$f_n(a,b)=\frac{\int_{\Delta_a}\prod_{i=1}^nx_i^{\alpha-\frac{n+1}{2}}\prod_{i=1}^n(1-x_i)^{-1/2}\prod_{i<j}|x_i-x_j|}{\int_{\Delta_b}\prod_{i=1}^nx_i^{\alpha-\frac{n+1}{2}}\prod_{i=1}^n(1-x_i)^{-1/2}\prod_{i<j}|x_i-x_j|}$$
where
$$\Delta_a=\{(x_1,...,x_n):0<x_1<a,0<x_2<a,...,0<x_n<a\}$$
and $1>a>b>0$, $\alpha>\frac{n+1}{2}$.

My question is, how can we upper bound $f_n(a,b)$? Is there a bound like some powers of $Ca/b$ for some constant $C>0$?

Comment: I have changed $\Delta_a$ to be a hypercube instead of the previous hyper rectangle.

Comment: if $C$ may depend on $n$, then of course we have $C_n(a/b)^M$ upper bound, where $a=n(\alpha-\frac{n+1}2)+{n\choose 2}$.

Comment: Sorry I do not quite get it.

Comment: I can't write a detailed answer at this time, so here is instead a sketch. If you normalize by $\Delta_1$ both integrals, then what you are asking is the ratio of probabilities that all eigenvalues are smaller than $a$ and the same with $b$. Since you have a large deviation principle at scale $n^2$ for the empirical measure of eigenvalues, with rate function $I(\mu)$, with a function $I$ that is explicit (involving the non-commutative entropy of $\mu$ - see section 2.6 in Anderson-Guionnet-Zeitouni's book on RMT), you can read of the answer:

Comment: $n^{-2} \log f_n(a,b)\to -\inf_{\mu: \mu([0,a])=1} I(\mu)+\inf_{\mu:\mu([0,b])=1} I(\mu)$. Just for completeness, the function $I$ is the following: $$I(\mu)=-\int\int \log|x-y|\mu(dx)\mu(dy)-\frac{1}{2}\int \log(x) \mu(dx)$$

Comment: Note that unsurprisingly, the leading order asymptotics does not depend on $\alpha$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Denote the numerator by $I(a)$. The change of variables $x_i=ay_i$ gives 
$$
I(a)=a^{n(\alpha-\frac{n+1}2)+\frac{n(n+1)}2}\times \\
\times\int_{[0,1]^n}\prod_{i=1}^ny_i^{\alpha-\frac{n+1}{2}}\prod_{i=1}^n(1-ay_i)^{-1/2}\prod_{i<j}|y_i-y_j|.
$$
The latter integral may be estimated using the two-sided estimates $1\leqslant (1-ay_i)^{-1/2}\leqslant (1-y_i)^{-1/2}$. So, we get $$c_1(n) a^{n(\alpha-\frac{n+1}2)+\frac{n(n+1)}2}\leqslant I(a)\leqslant c_2(n) a^{n(\alpha-\frac{n+1}2)+\frac{n(n+1)}2},$$
where $c_1(n)$ and $c_2(n)$ are corresponding integrals (actually $c_2(n)=I(1)$).
It implies
$$
\frac{I(a)}{I(b)}\leqslant \frac{c_2(n)}{c_1(n)}\cdot (a/b)^{n(\alpha-\frac{n+1}2)+\frac{n(n+1)}2}.
$$

You may get some explicit bounds for $c_2(n)/c_1(n)$
, for example as follows. 
We have
$$
c_2(n)=I(1)=\int_{[0,1]^n}\prod_{i=1}^ny_i^{\alpha-\frac{n+1}{2}}\prod_{i=1}^n(1-y_i)^{-1/2}\prod_{i<j}|y_i-y_j| dy_1\ldots dy_n,
$$
and $c_1(n)$ the same integral without $\prod_{i=1}^n(1-y_i)^{-1/2}$. In the integral for $c_2(n)$, change the variables: take $y_i=1-t_i^2$. You get
$$
c_2(n)=2^n\int_{[0,1]^n}\prod_{i=1}^n(1-t_i^2)^{\alpha-\frac{n+1}{2}}\prod_{i<j}|t_i^2-t_j^2| dt_1\ldots dt_n.
$$
Use the bounds $1-t_i^2=(1-t_i)(1+t_i)\leqslant 2(1-t_i)$, $|t_i^2-t_j^2|=|t_i-t_j|(t_i+t_j)\leqslant 2|t_i-t_j|$. We get 
$$
c_2(n)\leqslant 2^{n(\alpha-\frac{n+1}{2})+\frac{n(n+1)}2}
\int_{[0,1]^n}\prod_{i=1}^n(1-t_i)^{\alpha-\frac{n+1}{2}}\prod_{i<j}|t_i-t_j| dt_1\ldots dt_n=\\
=2^{n(\alpha-\frac{n+1}{2})+\frac{n(n+1)}2} c_1(n),
$$
the last equality follows from the change of variables $1-t_i=z_i$.

Is it ok for you or you need the estimates which are explicit w.r.t. $n$?

Comment: Yeah... I think I need to bound the ratio $c_1(n)/c_2(n)$... How can we do that?

Comment: That is very helpful! Thank you!